# How to derive the expected value of even powers of a standard normal random variable?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

I am trying to prove that, for a standard normal random variable $Z \sim N(0,1)$, ${\mathbb E}[z^n]=n!!$ for even values of $n$. What I'm doing is integrating the p.d.f. of $Z$ which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-x^2/2)$, i.e.,

$${\mathbb E}[z^n] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^n exp(-x^2/2)$$

While trying to use integration by parts, I'm unable to get either function into a form where the above reduces to some sort of a recurrence relation. Can you help?

Comment: Do you know the moment generating function and/or the characteristic function of the standard normal random variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
{\mathbb E}[z^n] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^n exp(-x^2/2)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[(n-1)x^{n-2}xe^{-x^2/2}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-(n-1)x^{n-2}e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n-2}e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n-1)!!e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
&= (n-1)!!
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't get the mental leaps here. Why is $\left[(n-1)x^{n-2}xe^{-x^2/2}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$ equal to zero? Why is $(n-1)x^{n-2}$ suddenly equal to $(n-1)!!$?

Comment: It is equal to 0 since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{e^{x^2/2}}=0$ for $\forall k\in\mathbb{R}$ and this is true for the case of $-\infty$ as well. The step between $(n-1)x^{n-2}$ and $(n-1)!!$ is just a repetition of the previous step. I continued the previous step until the exponent of $x$ becomes 0.