# what is the expectation value of a norm of a random variable from the standard normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Let's suppose $\zeta_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$ is a random variable from a normal distribution with mean zero and 1 standard deviation. Is that true that $E[|| \zeta_k ||^2]=p$?

Comment: "mean zero and zero standard deviation" suggests almost surely zero.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081271/how-to-derive-the-expected-value-of-even-powers-of-a-standard-normal-random-vari/4435797?noredirect=1#comment9285633_4435797. No, I have from an article that put $E[\zeta_k]=0$ and $E[\|\zeta_k\|^2]=p$. I do not know the reason.

Comment: @Raz . What has that link to do with your question ? Regarding $\zeta_k\in\mathbb R^p$ : Are the $p$ components of $\zeta_k$ independent ? If so, use the fact that the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances and you get $p$.

Comment: yes, p is the components of $\zeta_k$, I did not get your solution. We now that since $\zeta_k \in N(0,1)$, then $E[\zeta_k]=0$, now, how then $E[\|\zeta_k\|^2]=p$? Thanks

Comment: @Raz What's the definition of $\|\zeta_k\|^2$? Just write it down and use that each component of a standard normal distribution is a standard normal distribution itself